# Group Sum to N: working with list of lists

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and working on a problem where you take in a number, n,  and list, iL.  With these you check what consecutive numbers would be < than n and store it in a list.  You can have more than one list. I've created a function called groupSumtoN that would return this list of lists.

I've created a helper function helperToSum to recursively create the list and return the output, which takes the number n, input , and acc ( the result).

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
groupSumtoN :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupSumtoN n [] = []
groupSumtoN n iL = (helperToSum n iL [])

helperToSum n [] acc = acc
helperToSum n (x:xs) acc | (sum acc) + x < n = (helperToSum n xs (acc : x))
                         | (sum acc) + x > n = acc:(helperToSum n xs [x])
```

I get two infinite type errors, one for calling helperToSum from groupSumtoN and another in this line.

```
(sum acc) + x < n = (helperToSum n xs (acc : x))
```

As an example I have an example how this function should work below:

```
groupSumtoN 15 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7],[8],[9],[10]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please state the exact error messages, these contain a wealth of information. And I strongly recommend that you give a type signature for `helperToSum` as well, since this can help you pinpoint the source of errors like this.

Comment: One definite problem, which explains the "infinite type" error, is that `helperToSum` returns `acc` in one branch, and `acc:(<some expression>)` in another. Look at the type of `(:)` and you will realise these can never have the same type. And obviously all possible return values of a function must have the same type (the same as given in the type signature - which is one reason why including a type signature is helpful, then GHC will point out exactly which expression has the wrong type).

Comment: When you get a strange type error in Haskell, it often arises since the compiler tried to infer the type of your code, infers a type which is *not* what you expected, and then much later on fails, producing an error message based on a "wrong" assumption. The common solution here is adding more type annotations to the code. If you add a line `helperToSum :: .....` stating which type you expect, the compiler has more information, and will error out early, when your expectation is broken by the code, pointing out the bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base case:

```
helperToSum n [] acc = acc
```

Does not make much sense, since it expects a list of lists. You need to return a singleton list:

```
helperToSun n [] acc = [acc]
```

Another problem is that `(acc : x)` is not valid. `(:)` is a constructor of a list, and has type `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. You can not use it to append values. We could, for now, use `(x : acc)`. In that case, you will later need to reverse.

It is furthermore better to use `otherwise` as second guard. Here for example it is possible that the sum is exactly `n`, and that case is not covered right now.

With these problems in mind, we can fix the compilation errors, with the following function:

```
helperToSum :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
helperToSum n [] acc = [acc]
helperToSum n (x:xs) acc | (sum acc) + x <= n = (helperToSum n xs (x : acc))
                         | otherwise = acc:(helperToSum n xs [x])
```

But here the groups will be reversed, and furthermore it is not very efficient. We can make a more lazy variant that on the fly calculates how much space is left in a group, and aims to assign the items in the current, or the next group based on that condition:

```
groupSumtoN :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupSumtoN n = go n
    where go _ [] = [[]]
          go r (x:xs) | x <= r = let (t:tl) = go (r-x) xs in (x:t) : tl
                      | x > n = error "Item too large"
                      | otherwise = [] : go n (x:xs)
```

Here an empty lists, will produce a single group:

```
Prelude> groupSumtoN 15 []
[[]]
```

I leave it as an exercise to further improve this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This if my first functional language so its a learning experience.  I am able to get the correct output once I used the reverse function when concatenating acc to the function call.